# Can you make a simple hand-operated pump using two check valves?

Tags: valves

question is basically the title. I was wondering if it would be possible to connect a check valve on each end of a squeezable bladder in order to make a simple pump.

The purpose would be to make a demonstration model for children to illustrate how mechanical components can mimic biological (in this case the heart), and allowing them to squeeze the bladder would pump a visible fluid around.

It's for a college club that does engineering outreach events. Just trying to get kids interested in engineering but don't want to spend the club's money if the idea sounds unfeasible.

Thanks in advance

Comment: that's basically what a water pistol is

Comment: That's exactly what a bellows pump has been for a thousand years. [The Mini Bellows Metering Pumps operate on a positive displacement principle. The rotation of the motor shaft is transmitted into an up and down linear motion through an adjustable concentric crank mechanism. This motion provides a continuous compressing and relaxing force on the bellows module, forcing fluid between two check valves located in the module’s
valve body](https://www.gripumps.com/media/1387/gri-mini-bellows-pumps-overview-0819.pdf)

Answer (score 1):

one can find many examples, blood pressure machine hand pump is one.

The bladder has two check valves, one of them has a manual override valve to let the system reset after measuring the blood pressure!

Here is one available at Amazon for $9.

;

[image: hand pump]

Answer (score 0):

These bulb pumps
are also used to prime outboard motor fuel hoses. This sort of pump works exactly the same way your heart does. I designed my own "heart pump" with two check valves to move water into a plastic sink used in a portable emergency handwashing station. This was done using a round plastic electrical junction box topped off with a toilet plunger cup held in place with a hose clamp. Contact me at www.nielsenkillowatt for photos.